# Reading txt content into variable SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very simple question. My purpose here to retrieve login names from a txt file into a variable into SQL and query the SQL table while predicating against that same variable.
 So for example:

the txt file would have:

```
forde
blain
martin
Alex
```

so the idea to feed each name to a variable and output the designated computer name.

```
Declare @loginName varchar (25)
--open the file
--while the end of the file has not reached, read each line and place the name into @loginName variable 
select * 
from computerinfo
where loginname  = @loginname
```

I don't necessarily need to bulk import to a temp table at this point.

Thanks.

Comment: Bulk import is the only way you can read data using T-SQL. Otherwise you'll have to use SSIS, a custom tool or an OLEDB provider for CSV to use in combination with OPENROWSET.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624656/ssis-how-do-i-pull-a-sql-statement-from-a-file-into-a-string-variable

Answer (score 0):

i had to do this some weeks ago and the simple way i found was Powershell.

I had no SSIS else it's the best of course.

```
# You may want to adjust these
function Invoke-Sqlcmd2 
{ 
    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param( 
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$ServerInstance, 
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Database, 
    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Query, 
    [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Username, 
    [Parameter(Position=4, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$Password, 
    [Parameter(Position=5, Mandatory=$false)] [Int32]$QueryTimeout=600, 
    [Parameter(Position=6, Mandatory=$false)] [Int32]$ConnectionTimeout=15, 
    [Parameter(Position=7, Mandatory=$false)] [ValidateScript({test-path $_})] [string]$InputFile, 
    [Parameter(Position=8, Mandatory=$false)] [ValidateSet("DataSet", "DataTable", "DataRow")] [string]$As="DataRow" 
    ) 

    if ($InputFile) 
    { 
        $filePath = $(resolve-path $InputFile).path 
        $Query =  [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$filePath") 
    } 

    $conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection 

    if ($Username) 
    { $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};User ID={2};Password={3};Trusted_Connection=False;Connect Timeout={4}" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$Username,$Password,$ConnectionTimeout } 
    else 
    { $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$ConnectionTimeout } 

    $conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString 

    #Following EventHandler is used for PRINT and RAISERROR T-SQL statements. Executed when -Verbose parameter specified by caller 
    if ($PSBoundParameters.Verbose) 
    { 
        $conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors=$true 
        $handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {Write-Verbose "$($_)"} 
        $conn.add_InfoMessage($handler) 
    } 

    $conn.Open() 
    $cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn) 
    $cmd.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout 
    $ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet 
    $da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd) 
    [void]$da.fill($ds) 
    $conn.Close() 
    switch ($As) 
    { 
        'DataSet'   { Write-Output ($ds) } 
        'DataTable' { Write-Output ($ds.Tables) } 
        'DataRow'   { Write-Output ($ds.Tables[0]) } 
    } 

} #Invoke-Sqlcmd2

$files = @(get-childitem "filelocationformultiplefile" -include *.txt -exclude *.bak -recurse | where-object {($_.LastWriteTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-0))-and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)})
if ($files -ne $NULL)
{

    for ($idx = 0; $idx -lt $files.Length; $idx++)
        {
            $file = $files[$idx]

        $Query = @"
Bulk INSERT db.dbo.tbl from '$file' with (FirstRow = 1, FieldTerminator ='";', RowTerminator = '\n')
"@
        Invoke-sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance "servername" -Database "db" -Query $Query
        }
}
```

And i'm not crazy, except the 10 ending lines everything else is coming from a microsoft official blog.

You don't need everything, powershell is present on every computer, it requires to save this in a file with extension ps1 and configure the 4 variables $fileout2 -> $tablename