# How to run multiple stored procedures in parallel using ssis?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

We have a list of stored procedures (more than 1000) in a table which need to be executed every morning.

The stored procedures do not have any dependency with each other.

We have tried while loop and cursor it used to takes a lot of time in execution.

We taught of creating job for each stored procedure and call them using `sp_start_job` (`sp_start_job` is called in async manner) we got level of parallelism.

**Problem** arise when a new stored procedure is added to list and it became huge.

1. some time ppl missed to create job related new stored procedure
2. DB got bombarded with a no of jobs (manageability issue for DBA)

**Note**: list of may altered any day (stored procedures can be added or removed from list).

Comment: Simply use _many_ while loops in your SSIS package. If you don't add precedence constraints they run in parallel.

Comment: Nick can you please describe little more  .. i create a loop and execute sql task but it did not get executed in parallel..

Comment: Drop another for loop container on then page. Now you have two containers that will run at the same time. Just make sure that the two for-loop's use mutually exclusive datasets. i.e. you need a where clause in each one to filter the list of sp's to be executed

Comment: You might want some less arbitrary method of defining parallelism, i.e., add a column to your SP list that tags it in a group to be executed in. Then you can tune it really well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SPs run for longer, I would have categorized the 1000 SPs into 5-10 numbers, then 1 SSIS package for each category and then Agent Jobs for each package. Then, schedule those jobs at same time.

There are many ways like Loops, Scripting and multiple factors to achieve it. You can test with different ways and go with the best one.

Note: Performance of the SSIS execution depends on your Memory, Processor and Hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @ Nick.MacDermaid - you can utilize MaxConcurrentExecutables property of package to implement custom parallelism. Of course you would need to have multiple containers and corresponding stored proc groups.

[Parallel Execution in SSIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlperf/2007/05/11/implement-parallel-execution-in-ssis/)

> MaxConcurrentExecutables, a property of the package. It defines how
>   many tasks (executables) can run simultaneously. It defaults to -1
>   which is translated to the number of processors plus 2. Please note
>   that if your box has hyperthreading turned on, it is the logical
>   processor rather than the physically present processor that is
>   counted.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the following piece of code to get basically write the script of running all your stored procedures if you add a new procedure it will automatically be added to the list

```
SELECT'EXEC '+SPECIFIC_NAME [Command] + ';'
FROM information_schema.routines 
WHERE routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

After this you take the result set put it into a tab delimited text file and save the file in a location.

use this link to import the text into a execute SQL task the first answer works well

[SSIS: How do I pull a SQL statement from a file into a string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624656/ssis-how-do-i-pull-a-sql-statement-from-a-file-into-a-string-variable)

execute the task and it should work, if you need to narrow the ;ist of procedures you can specify a specific prefix in the name of the procedure and use that in the where clause

It will run in serial, sorry i dont have enough rep to comment yet